# Animation starts shifting after some time

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm designing a page with divs that are animated with jQuery animate. This includes moving the divs and scaling them (by setting the width and height among the .animate() parameters).  I don't see any flaws in the animation using my MacBook, using both chrome and firefox, but my I have been told that the divs starts shifting out of position if the page is left alone for 8-10 minutes.

1. How might this be possible? Could it be that on a slower computer, the animations are not synchronised? I am animating 5 divs at the same time and I set an internval (every 8 seconds) for the animation to recurre and I also set the animation speed to slow.
2. I am animating the divs with something like `left += 200px` instead of for example`left = 450px` because in firefox all the divs will jump to the left side of the screen, and some of them jumps so far left that they come out of the screen.

   I think it's because I'm using a parent container div to contain the moving divs and use `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto` to center this container div and when setting the `left` attribute of the animated divs, firefox treats them as having `left:0` at the beginning of the animation. I set the position of the container div as relative but the animated divs as absolute (as I don't want them to interfere with one another's position). Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you set this up in JSFiddle or give a link where we can see? I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with far less code and far fewer headaches.

**1. Store your tablet position attributes in classes**

```
.tablet1{
  height:100px;
  width:140px;
  margin-left:-540px;
  top: 200px;
  z-index:10;
}
```

**2. Use a general function to handle all your transitions.**

JQuery UI will do all the work for you if you use `switchClass`

```
switchTabletsRight = function(){
  var i, next, max = 5;
  for(i = 1; i <= max; i++){
    next = (i < max)? i + 1 : 1;
    $(".tablet" + i).switchClass("tablet" + i, "tablet" + next);
  }
};​
```

**3. Call the general function with setInterval.**

```
var loop = setInterval(function(){
  switchTabletsRight();
},2000);
```

Here's the JSfiddle proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/nRHag/6/

Comment: Thanks, it's a very good concept. But after implementing it, I found some problems: After some time, the animation starts to be unsynchronised, tablets will move at different timings instead of at the same time. Then as I have a large tablet in the middle, with margin-left of -300px, when I move it to the right, which have a margin-left of +400ish, the movement becomes unnatural and does not behave like the other tablets

Comment: If you're using switchClass it's impossible for tablets to end up in an in-between state.  The fiddle runs for hours with no degradation, do you have a code sample where I can see how you implemented it?